# Is it possible to execute the command line inside SpatiaLite?

Tags: spatialite, command-line

Let's say I have a dataset filled with points on SpatiaLite and I don't have these points address location on this database. So, I make a new column on it for adding this `address` as the following:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN address TEXT
```

I'd like to execute commands available on the command line in my Operating System... Something like the following:

```
UPDATE 'my_table' SET address = externalCommand(getLocation, AsText(geometry))
```

In this pseudo example, `getLocation` is a script that I've created and `externalCommand` would be a way of accessing the command line with SpatiaLite. For example, my `getLocation` script is the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
  
point="$1"
latlong=($(echo "$point" | sed 's/)//g' | sed 's/^.*(//g'))
lat="${latlong[1]}"
long="${latlong[0]}"

curl -s "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=$lat&lon=$long&zoom=10&format=json" | jq '.display_name'
sleep 0.5
```

This script is functional (it relies on `curl`, `sed` and `jq`), I'm using the OSM nominatim API in order to get the address of a specific latitude and longitude. If I execute this script with `getLocation "POINT(-46.384794 -23.513442)"`, I see:

```
"São Paulo, Região Imediata de São Paulo, Região Metropolitana de São Paulo, Região Geográfica Intermediária de São Paulo, São Paulo, Região Sudeste, Brasil"
```

In my view, if I can execute the command line from inside SpatiaLite, I can also do stuff like that and use the `UPDATE` statement to get the address of points dynamically using an API like the OSM one... Is it possible? Can I execute commands available on the operating system in a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1**: update each line of your database table using ogrinfo and WHERE statement (individual line update)

My first approach differs from your expectation. I do not try to run a command within Spatialite but to call Spatialite from the command line and provide the infos as variables to customize the SQL query.

You can try the following. My comments in the code explain the changes done

```bsh
long=-1.5543
lat=47.2186
# Added -r option (for raw) to jq and assigned result to content variable
content=$(curl -s "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=$lat&lon=$long&zoom=10&format=json" | jq -r '.display_name')

# Update using ogrinfo to Spatialite db yourfile.sqlite
# I've added a where condition you need to customized or you will update all records
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "UPDATE 'my_table' SET address = '"$content"' WHERE your_identifier_col = 'your_identifier_value'" yourfile.sqlite
```

**Approach 2**: update using Spatialite functions available through GDAL (no need for WHERE)

You can also play with existing geocoding functions available within GDAL (docs at https://gdal.org/user/sql_sqlite_dialect.html#ogr-geocoding-functions)

```bsh
# Standalone demo, no update
# I change query template to call endpoint to call API to return JSON and then filter JSON
# Not really useful here but useful if consuming other services
ogrinfo --config OGR_GEOCODE_REVERSE_QUERY_TEMPLATE "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat={lat}&lon={lon}" -dialect -SQLite -sql "SELECT json_extract(ogr_geocode_reverse(2.0,49.0,'raw'), '$')" input.sqlite
```

Second choice, more simple as it use GDAL supported provider for Nominatim

```bsh
ogrinfo --config OGR_GEOCODE_SERVICE OSM_NOMINATIM -dialect -SQLite -sql "SELECT ogr_geocode_reverse(2.0,49.0,'display_name')" input.sqlite
```

For your particular case, to update your field address using columns for lon and lat from your database table

```bsh
# Update with display_name content from nominatim
ogrinfo --config OGR_GEOCODE_SERVICE OSM_NOMINATIM -dialect -SQLite -sql "UPDATE 'my_table' SET address = ogr_geocode_reverse(lon,lat,'display_name')" input.sqlite
```

You can also use `ogr_geocode_reverse(geometry,'display_name')` if your input coordinates are in your geometry and they are points instead of `ogr_geocode_reverse(lon,lat,'display_name')` You can also change delay adding option `--config OGR_GEOCODE_DELAY 0.5`(1 sed by default). Other options to change common configs to  `ogr_geocode`/`ogr_geocode_reverse` behaviour https://gdal.org/doxygen/ogr__geocoding_8h.html#ac3e12320a8046248b992fd0ce4731903

Comment: My idea by executing the command line inside a query was that I'd be able to get the address of that point based on the actual data that's inside the database. On your samples the point location is hardcoded, right? In this logic, I'd still have to take the points out of the database together with an ID in order to update all points correctly. And also execute ogrinfo as many times as the number of lines on the database.. I can see a script following this logic of getting the points from the database and updating them line by line inside a loop. I'm wondering if I can avoid this loop though.

Comment: Edited my answer. 2nd approach do what you expect: no WHERE to get addresses for each line

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something... But after executing it I just see that the process is being executed but with no additional logs. Is it executed silently the number of lines of my database seconds?

Comment: You can see what's happening by adding option `--config CPL_DEBUG ON` to get more verbose infos

Comment: Thanks, it's showing the location updates now... Apparently, it changes the database after everything is finished because if I cancel the process in the middle of the execution I see no changes inside the database.

Comment: You may update by chunk using `rowid` e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39393095/update-large-sqlite-database-in-chunks Although geocode works, if it fails, it may behave like a blackbox you are unable to control.  If you only update some records addresses using chunk, it will be easier to locate if an issue happens